# Find count of all pairs in table by specific columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with columns like week, shop, brand. For example

```py
week shop brand
1    1    cola
1    2    sprite
1    3    pepsi
1    4    pepsi
2    1    cola 
2    2    sprite
2    3    sprite
2    4    sprite
```

I want to find how much shops meet a couple of brands every week
The result table is:

```py
week brand1  brand2  num_shops
1    cola    sprite  1
1    cola    pepsi   2
1    sprite  cola    1
1    sprite  pepsi   1  
1    pepsi   cola    2
1    pepsi   sprite  1    
2    cola    sprite  3
2    sprite  cola    3
```

I know that I should do probably

```py
def func(x):
    x1 = x.merge(x,on=["week"],suffixes =('1','2'))
    x1.groupby(["brand1","brand2"]).apply(func1)
    return x1

def func1(x):
#make count

data.groupby(["week"]).apply(func)
```

Can I do it faster if I have a lot of data?

Edit: The column num_shops formed as follows: We take one week. Look at all the  pairs of brands on it and we look at how many pairs  repeated. For example we first get table like this and then get information about num_shops:

```py
week brand1  brand2 
1    cola    sprite  
1    cola    pepsi
1    cola    pepsi   
1    sprite  cola    
1    sprite  pepsi     
1    pepsi   cola
1    pepsi   cola    
1    pepsi   sprite      
2    cola    sprite  
2    cola    sprite  
2    cola    sprite  
2    sprite  cola
2    sprite  cola
2    sprite  cola
```

Comment: Can you please explain your logic on how the num_shops is calculated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) with [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) for filter out same values in both `brand` and then count by [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df = (df.merge(df,on=["week"], suffixes= ('1','2'))
       .query("brand1 != brand2")
       .groupby(['week','brand1','brand2'], sort=False)
       .size()
       .reset_index(name='num_shops'))
print (df)
   week  brand1  brand2  num_shops
0     1    cola  sprite          1
1     1    cola   pepsi          2
2     1  sprite    cola          1
3     1  sprite   pepsi          2
4     1   pepsi    cola          2
5     1   pepsi  sprite          2
6     2    cola  sprite          3
7     2  sprite    cola          3
```

EDIT:

Your solution should be changed:

```
def func(x):
    x1 = x.merge(x,on=["week"],suffixes =('1','2'))
    x1 = x1[x1['brand1'].ne(x1['brand2'])]
    return x1.groupby(["brand1","brand2"], sort=False).size()

df = df.groupby(["week"]).apply(func).reset_index(name='num_shops')
print (df)
   week  brand1  brand2  num_shops
0     1    cola  sprite          1
1     1    cola   pepsi          2
2     1  sprite    cola          1
3     1  sprite   pepsi          2
4     1   pepsi    cola          2
5     1   pepsi  sprite          2
6     2    cola  sprite          3
7     2  sprite    cola          3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, but I have a table with 2000000 rows, so merging it results in memory error. So I can't use this function for full table.

Comment: @JackHavis - Added your solution, can you check how working with real data?

Comment: @ jezrael Thanks. No error now, but a lot of computational time

Comment: @JackHavis - Yes, I know. Unfortunately if working with large data need a lot of RAM for pandas, or slow solution...